# Linq result as collection of parent (User) object

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have this Linq query that (correctly) supplies met static data from a User. I now manually perform the 'Include' of the User table. What I'm look for is that the result of this query actually becomes the collection of the parent User object.

If i select multiple user names (s.User.Name) instead of a single i use now, i would only get returned the same number of User objects as usernames i search for with their Statistics (User.Statistics) collection filled with the data like returned by the query below.

```
var statistics =    (( 
        from s in db.Statistics
        where s.User.ScreenName == screenName && 
              s.CreateDate > EntityFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Now, days)
        group s by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(s.CreateDate) into dg

        let maxDate = dg.Max(x => x.CreateDate)
        from s2 in db.Statistics
        where s2.User.ScreenName == screenName && 
              s2.CreateDate == maxDate
        orderby s2.CreateDate
        select s2) as ObjectQuery<Statistic>).Include("User").ToList();
```

### Update 18-05-2012 15:41

Simply returning s2.User won't work as it will return the user as many times as there are rows returned from statistic table, I would only like to get 1 user object and have it's statistics collection (User.Statistics) filled with the result of the query.

Answer (score 1):

return the user in your select clause:

```
var users=
    ( 
    from s in db.Statistics
    where s.User.ScreenName == screenName && 
          s.CreateDate > EntityFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Now, days)
    group s by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(s.CreateDate) into dg

    let maxDate = dg.Max(x => x.CreateDate)
    from s2 in db.Statistics
    where s2.User.ScreenName == screenName && 
          s2.CreateDate == maxDate
    orderby s2.CreateDate
    select s2.User.User       // <--------
    ).ToList();
```

to get a unique list of users add `.Distinct()`.  If that doesn't work here's a guess (without knowing your object model) on how to get the users:

```
 var allusernames=
    ( 
    from s in db.Statistics
    where s.User.ScreenName == screenName && 
          s.CreateDate > EntityFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Now, days)
    group s by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(s.CreateDate) into dg

    let maxDate = dg.Max(x => x.CreateDate)
    from s2 in db.Statistics
    where s2.User.ScreenName == screenName && 
          s2.CreateDate == maxDate
    orderby s2.CreateDate
    select s2.User.UserName       // <--------
    ).ToList();

var distinct users =
    (
        from u in users
        where allusernames.Contains(u.UserName)
        select u
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: This does not work as a simply the x number of the same User returned for each corresponding statistic entry. I would like to get 1 user (as i only query for 1 user here) and the Statistic collection of the User filled (User.Statistics) with the result of the query.

Comment: Without knowing your data model I can;t give you a query that will return exactly one user.  See updated answer for a few guesses.

Answer (score 0):

You want a query of Users, with the Statistics property only filled with the data you want, instead of the data in the database.

If you write a standard "include query" of users, you'll get all of the Statistics data, which you can then filter locally.  In this case, more data may be loaded than you actually desire.

```
from u in db.Users.Include("Statistics")
where u.ScreenName == theScreenName
select u;
```

You could also write a query that only loads the statistics you want in the result type.  In this case, the statistics property of the User instances will not be populated.

```
from u in db.Users
where u.ScreenName == theScreenName
let stats = u.Statistics.Where(...)
select new {User = u, Stats = stats.ToList()};
```

---

There is no way to get what you are asking for in LinqToEntities (User.Statistics partially populated).  In LinqToSql - we would use [`DataLoadOptions.AssociateWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534221.aspx) to do that job.

Once again, LinqToSql wins over EF.